# LocalActivityManager destroyActivity with animation

Tags: android, animation, back, activitygroup

I wanna add animation effect when a activity call back method.And I use activityGroup to implement activitymanger  and use LocalActivityManager to start and back any activity.

when start an activity  add the animation use the follow code

```
public static void startActivity(Intent intent, String id) {

    View view = mLocalActivityManager.startActivity(id,
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();

    Animation hyperspaceJump = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivityGroup,
            R.anim.dync_in_from_right);
    view.startAnimation(hyperspaceJump);

    view.setTag(id);
    mPreviousActivityTag = getCurrentActivityTag();
    mViewContainer.addView(view);
}
```

but i don't know how to add the animation effect when an activity return back to the one , which start the cur activity. the back method is like that

```
public static void removeCurrentActivity() {

    String tag = getCurrentActivityTag();
    if (com.ct.ipaipai.global.Utily.isStringEmpty(tag) == false) {

        int cnt = getActivityCount();
        mViewContainer.removeViewAt(cnt - 1);
        View view = mLocalActivityManager.destroyActivity(tag, true).getDecorView();
    }
}
```

any one know that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which `ActivityGroup` you are using, but when I used [`ActivityGroup`](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) sometimes in past, I did something like this

```
String tag = getCurrentActivityTag();
LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
Animation animation = null;
animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.de_rail);
Window oldWindow = manager.getCurrentActivity().getWindow();
if(oldWindow != null)
{
    View v =oldWindow.getDecorView();
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_pink_background);
    v.startAnimation(animation);                
}
manager.destroyActivity(tag, true);
// now set old Activity View
Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
if(newWindow != null)
{
    View view = newWindow.getDecorView();
    setContentView(view);           
}
```

where `R.anim.de_rail`, which was actually `de_rail.xml` was something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="400" />
```

You can find [my modified version here](http://pastie.org/3541407). It shows animation on start child `Activity` and finishing child `Activity`.